# How to get the ID of any user given the Username in Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import os

flist = []

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('?ID'):
      for i in ID.split()[1].split('#'):
         flist.append(i)
         print(flist)

  print(discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), name = flist[0], discriminator = flist[1]).id)
     

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I want to have a bot get the id of a use just by entering the the name and the hashtag number but it returns an error that the final line has nonetype. How could I fix this so it shows the id as a string?

Comment: What is the `ID` variable (used in `ID.split()[1].split('#')`)? Also, do you mean any user in the *whole* of discord, or just users that are in any servers with the bot?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you use `commands.Bot`

Comment: Yes thank you I just learned about bot commands and I started using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me recommend you to use the [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands) extension for discord.py, it will greatly help you to make commands.

You just need to get a discord.Member or discord.User in this case. Since these classes have built in converters, you can use them as typehints to create an instance:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', ...)

@bot.command()
async def showid(ctx, member: discord.Member): # a Union could be used for extra 'coverage'
    await ctx.send(f'ID: {member.id}')
```

Using a typehint in this case allows the command user to invoke the command like:
`?showid <id>`, `?showid <mention>`, `?showid <name#tag>`, `?showid <nickname>` etc with the same result.

If you don't want to use `discord.ext.commands`, you can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) as well:

```py
client = discord.Client(...)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...

    if message.content.startswith('?ID'):
        member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=message.content.split()[1])
        await message.channel.send(member.id)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you the bot command way worked perfectly and I will start using it!